# There was an error running the selected code generator: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, version = 2.0.1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When I was creating a `Controller` and a `View` by `MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework` I got an error.

The Error is:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Could not
>   load file or assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, version =
>   2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
>   [image: The error image]

Creating MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework:
[image: Creating MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework]

How can I solve this problem?

I use `Visual Studio Version 15.5.2` and version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is `2.0.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I updated the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` to `version 2.0.3` and now it does work right.

Comment: Works, but I needed to close my solution, reopen and build before Scaffolding again.

Answer (score 6):

Go to NugetPackage Manager and update the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package

Answer (score 4):

For me none of the above solutions worked. I had to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design packages even though I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package added to my project.

Edit project in VS 2017 and add these lines

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
```

Comment: Same solution works also in 2019 when adding a scaffolded item and dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design.dll throws "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference". Just add those packages in their relevant version to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Update your packages or it can happen when you have an older SDK. Download a new .NET Core SDK and runtime from www.microsoft.com/net

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but mine was something with the versioning of visual studio.

I went to Visual Studio Installer and it notified me that I had to restart my computer

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error:

[image: error running selected code generator]

**Running Preview 2019 and .NET Core 3**.

I moved the Nuget pkg sources up in my list.

I was attemping to add a new Controller and I would get this error every time.

I also noticed that for some reason I chose not to set up SSL but I had the setting in my *launchSettings.json*.

I deleted the setting for ssl and built the app and ran it.
After the successful run I could add the Controller without the error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow these Steps:-

> From Tools

- Select **NuGet Package Manager**
  -> **Manage NuGet Packages For Solution**
  click on  ->**Updates** Select the checkbox **Select All**
  ->Select Your Project from right hand side -> Click on **Upadate**

Answer (score -1):

[image: VS2019Preview]Having the same error, after downloaded VS2019"PREVIEW" and then opened a core 3.0 project there I was able to scaffold content no errors at all..